# Firefox 57 favicon is not recognized

Tags: firefox, favicon

Since the version 57 of Firefox (Quantum) it appears that none of the favicons I include on my site is being recognised. This are all the formats I have included:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/icons/my-favicon.ico">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/icons/my-favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/icons/my-favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/icons/my-favicon-24x24.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/icons/my-favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/icons/my-favicon-48x48.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/icons/my-favicon-64x64.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/icons/my-apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/icons/my-apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/icons/my-apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/icons/my-apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/icons/my-apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/icons/my-apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/icons/my-apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/icons/my-apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/icons/my-apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
```

All the paths are valid and it seem to work in any other major browser. Does the new version of Firefox require some specific type for the favicon? Even if they introduced something new it is strange that it's not falling back to any of the common formats...

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: No errors/warnings in the console

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after updating to 57 as well.  I have no idea what the problem was, but clearing the cache and restarting Firefox fixed it.